# Is it secure to use SHA hash of the secret value as its external ID?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sha, secret-key, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to design the system where I need to store users' secret values in database (private and public key strings). The storing of secrets itself will be done with the help of HashiCorp Vault. But I have one more requirement that disallows to store two equal pairs (private key + public key). 
As far as I am not able to check keys uniqueness before storing I have to store hash of the original secrets. My idea to to calculate SHA hash from secret data and compare it with already saved hashes. So, I wonder is it working solution and can I use this digest as an external ID for accessing data (because hash imply the uniqueness of the data entry). Hope for your help.

Answer (score 4):

> My idea to to calculate SHA hash from secret data and compare it with already saved hashes

I'd assume cryptographic hash is best option you have when there is no other unique identifier

> (because hash imply the uniqueness of the data entry)

And that's wrong assumption. Regardless cryptographic hashes are designed to have negligible collision probability (probability that two inputs are having the same hash value), principially there is still some (very small) probability.

For controlled (formated) inputs I'd say the collision probability is so miniscule,  that you could boldly use the hashes as unique identifiers, but prepare to handle a very seldom case that a collision occurs (probably you could post it and become famous)

> calculate SHA hash from secret data

Concerning security - it is very hard (=impossible) to compute the input value based on its hash (assuming cryptographic hash currently considered as secure)

Beware of the space size - if you have say 1000 known values, it is trival to check which secret value has certain hash.  Assuming you store keypairs, it should be ok

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to use Bcrypt instead of SHA-256 for better entropy.